# redirect public_html folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain, public-html

I have two domain name

- www.domain.com
- www.parked.com

I have 3 folders inside the public_html (www) folder

- folder1
- folder2
- folder3

i want a wildcard using htaccess code to redirect the domain name to `folder2` so it be like this:

```
www.domain.com/  =>  public_html/folder2/
www.domain.com/forum  => public_html/folder2/forum
www.domain.com/support =>  public_html/folder2/support

or even subdomains:
www.forum.domain.com  => public_html/folder2/forum
www.support.domain.com  =>  public_html/folder2/support
www.[*random*].domain.com  =>  public_html/folder2/
```

with www. and without it

and the same for www.parked.com to folder3

and any attempt to access folder1 through e.g. www.domain.com/folder1 it then search for folder1 only inside folder2 not inside public_html .

i will deeply appreciate the help

regards

Comment: have a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Some of your wishes

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)forum.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/folder2/forum/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)support.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/folder2/support/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/folder2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT:**

So, if the input is the url

**www.domain.com/index.html** you will be redirect to

**www.domain.com/folder2/index.html**

The Condition

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain.com [NC]
```

means:

If there is "**domain.com**" in %{HTTP_HOST} do the **rule**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/folder2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

means:

- $1 is a variable. If the request was for http://example.com/foo/bar,
  then %1 would contain example.com and $1 would contain foo/bar.

[You see this page it is a good explanation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html#regex)

- For **EVERY Test** in your browser don't forget to **clear the
  browser-cache**

Comment: thanks for the reply and basically what i meant is a wildcard to redirect any subdomain to folder2 and domain.com to folder2...

Comment: that's what it does. Redirect any domain.com to **"//www.domain.com/folder2 !**"

Comment: yh sorry to confuse you :S but i wanted it to read `www.domain.com/folder2/index.html` as `www.domain.com/index.html` and ignores the `index.html` page inside `public_html`